# React Material UI icon passed in props --> to jsx (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I use an icon from the library of material UI in React environment. I pass this icon as a property to child react element and I want to render it inside this child.

So if in general you just need to:

```
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';

...

render(
       <DeleteIcon/>
)
```

now I got it as a property within the child element, and this is my code for the child:

```
export const InteractiveListItem: React.FC<{ Icon?: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> }> = (props) => {

    return (
        {props.Icon}  ------> not rendered!
    )
```

**How do I "convert" this ovverrideableComponent into acceptable ReactElement?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you pass props in the right way: `Icon={<DeleteIcon />}`, as you specified this in your InteractiveListItem component.